# How to add alt attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, blogger

I am facing a problem, I have the below blogger template which has the following HTML

```html
<a href="<data:post.url/>" style="background:url(<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover"></a>
```

I am facing an `alt` attribute error. So, if someone could kindly tell me how to add `alt` attribute in above html.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="#"><img src="pathofyourimg" alt="No Image Available" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `alt` attribute can be applied to an image to specify an alternate text.

Ex: `<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face">`

You can wrap an image inside the `<a` and specify alt attribute for the image.

```
<a href="<data:post.url/>">

  <image src="your image source" alt="This is my image">
</a>
```